# Is there a way to "discard" the output argument of std::getline()?

Tags: c++

In C, `getchar()` can be used to get a character from the input buffer(`char c = getchar();`), but it is also possible to use the function as a key press detector by ignoring the return value.

```cpp
char c = getchar(); // get a character
getchar(); // detect pressing the enter key
```

In C++, I can use `std::string in; std::getline(std::cin, in);` to get input. `std::getline()` seems to only accept an `std::string` reference for its second argument. Is there anything I can do to avoid having to declare a dummy variable?

```cpp
std::string in; // dummy variable
std::getline(std::cin, in); // discard the input anyway
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your first sentence talks about using `getchar` but shows code using `getline`. Which do you mean? If `getchar` works for what you want in C, why not use `std::getchar` in C++? Also, never use `char c = getchar();`; it should be `int c = getchar();`, because you need to be able to distinguish `EOF`.

Comment: There are other functions you can use to extract characters (see e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get ). What's your end goal, here?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to use `getchar()` for the C example. I was trying to point out the desired effect. Sure I can use `std::getchar()` in C++, but that would be using `<cstdio>` in addition to the `<iostream>` I'm already using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is [`std::cin::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).  Using

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You will pass over all of the character in the stream until you hit a newline character, thus discarding the current line.

You can change the `'\n'` to any other character and `ignore` will read until it hits that character.  For instance using `' '`, will allow you to skip the current "word".

Comment: I was hoping to cut down the amount of typing I need by omitting a dummy variable, but I guess I did ask for a way to ignore the "output" of `std::getline()`.

Comment: @404NameNotFound Good news is you can wrap this in a function like `void ignore_line() { std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); }` and now in your code, you just write `ignore_line();`.

Comment: Note this way is superior over using a dummy variable in getline, because the latter allocates and copies all the data, while this answer's code does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
[]{ std::string s; return std::getline(std::cin, s); };
```

Is mostly equivalent to

```
[]{ std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); };
```

The differences are:

1. [`.ignore()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is probably more efficient, as it simply discards read input.
2. [`std::getline()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) doesn't affect [`.gcount()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount).